# Using contains operator for array of objects in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, member-access-enumeration

I have a powershell object array like this

```
$EdosContainers= @([pscustomobject]@{Container='FoundationObjectStoreConfigMetadata';PartitionKey='/templateName'}
       [pscustomobject]@{Container='FoundationObjectStoreObjectInformation';PartitionKey='/processExecutionId'}
       [pscustomobject]@{Container='FoundationObjectStoreObjectMetadata';PartitionKey='/processExecutionId'}
       [pscustomobject]@{Container='FoundationObjectStoreConfigMetadataTransfomed';PartitionKey='/templateName'})
```

But I need to check whether a given value exists in the array or not in the container attribute.

I know we can use -contains method for checking the existence of an item in array. But since mine is an object array how can we accomplish this?

Comment: So, you want to be able to do something like `$EdosContainers -contains ([pscustomobject]@{Container='SomeContainerName';PartitionKey='/partition/key'})`?

Comment: `$EdosContainers.PartitionKey -contains '/templateName'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), which extracts all `.Container` property values from the array's *elements* by directly applying the property access to the *array*, allowing you to use `-contains`:

```
# -> $true
$EdosContainers.Container -contains 'FoundationObjectStoreConfigMetadataTransfomed'
```

---

If you want to avoid the implicit creation of an array with *all* `.Container` values, use the [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where):

```
[bool] $EdosContainers.Where(
  { $_.Container -eq 'FoundationObjectStoreConfigMetadataTransfomed' }, 
  'First'  # Stop, once a match is found.
)
```

While this is more memory-efficient than using member-access enumeration, it also noticeably slower with large arrays.

Comment: My pleasure, @SandeepThomas. I later saw that Omkar76 suggested that your question is a duplicate, which I think is correct, so I'm closing it as such.